# The logic behind calculating board game territory (GO)

Tags: javascript, logic, flood-fill

so im making the board game GO for javascript and im having trouble counting the territories. If you didnt know, GO is like a complex checkers where you place stones horizontally and vertically instead of diagonally. A territory comes when the game has ended and you have made a border of your stones (the board edges count as anyones).

[image: territory]

So the image above is what i have so far.

White = player 1,  Black = player 2,  Green = territory

So the green only comes at the end of the game. The game has now finished, black has control of the top left corner of the board taking 2 prisoners. The group inside has been identified and coloured in green. Problem is, how do i know what player the green territory belongs to?

Any human can see black owns all sides/ border of the territory (remember the board edges are anyones). It starts to get hard when there are prisoners inside. I could just check every cell adjacent to every green cell. If there is black and white, its not a territory but that wouldnt work if there is prisoners.

One way im thinking might be an option is to try identify the border going around it. If i can do that i can easily check whos territory it is. Calculating the border peices would be easy with a square but a circle or any morphed shape? im not sure.

Any help is appriciated :)

Comment: You would have to create your own algorithm for it

Comment: well yeh i gathered that, but what would the logic of that algorithim be? I just had a realisation that i could scroll through every peice in the group. If it has green on all sides, its in the middle and can be removed to identify the border. Not sure if that would work with prisioners

Comment: I have no clue how Go works.  Do you need to find paths of pieces that divide the board (since you said floodfill) - check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631576/using-recursion-to-find-paths-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: Ive already calculated the divisions of the board. I used floodfill to do this and coloured the group in green.

Comment: I can give you some examples of game algorithms I've made, ones a minesweeper game that goes from left to right for each row top to bottom and the other is a maze generator that checks if it is solvable or not though I don't know if they would be much help and there not well commented

Comment: hmm i dont think minesweeper or a maze generator would help with this specificly. In this example its just working out which players owns the green section by surrounding it. Thankyou for offering you, very kind :)

Comment: Your floodfill algorithm presumably can know what color of piece was the border of the fill

Comment: It would but the borders of prisoners would also be there.  For example b12 is going right, its detected what it thinks is a border and has stopped. In reality its not a border, its just a prisoner.

Comment: Could you add data to each square denoting its state like territory or prisoner, etc and flood fill using that information?

Comment: Yeh each stone already has data saying its state. But the thing is, if i do a flood fill on the green squares, it will think the 2 white squares are borders as the flood will end there. So i will have the border i want, but also a border inside around each prisoner if you get what i mean

Comment: There are well-known, established algorithms. Search for them and use them. You could start with http://senseis.xmp.net/?ComputerGoAlgorithms#toc3.  By the way, it's not at all clear to me that White's two stones are dead. In fact, I'm pretty sure they're alive.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this very effectively in the end using my own algorithm.

It will first identify the territory in question and get the lowX, lowY, highX, highY. So in this case it would be 0, 0, 5, 5 respectivly. I then do a for loop like this:

```
    for (var j = lowX; j < highX + 1; j++)
    {       
        var lowColumnY = null;
        var highColumnY = null;

        for (var k = 0; k < territories[i].length; k++)
        {               
            if (territories[i][k].x == j)
            {
                if ((lowColumnY == null) || (territories[i][k].y < lowColumnY))
                {
                    lowColumnY = territories[i][k].y;
                    console.log(lowColumnY);
                }

                if ((territories[i][k].y > highColumnY) || (highColumnY == null))
                {
                    highColumnY = territories[i][k].y;
                }
            }                               
        }
```

So that scrolls through all the columns of the territory and works out the low and high point which are the first 2 variables declared. I then repeat the for loop for the Y and in the end im left with every coordinate of the border. I have demonstrated this by drawing red circles so its easy to visualist and as you can see it doesnt interfere with any prisoners.

[image: territory]

So lastly i just check each colour of the stones where the red circles are. If there is any conflicting colours, it cant be a territory. As in this case the only colour was black, we know its a black territory.

Comment: also @torazaburo you now have egg on your face for saying it wouldnt work :)

Answer (score -1):

Im going to post an idea myself and try this method. So i will first get the most left column in the territory, in this case its index 0. i will use a for loop to scroll through every column finding out the most up and the most down stone in the column. So first is column 0. the most up stone is 0 and the most down is 5. (ignore the board markings). As that must be the top and bottom border for this shape I will check the stones above the top one and below the bottom one and note them down.

As the top of stone 0,0 is the edge of the board, its marked "both". Now for the bottom, below it will be marked "black". We now have an owner of this territory. I will repeat this for all the columns and then all the rows and if it gets any conflicting owner, i will break the loop as it cant be a territory.

I just thought of this in my head and im going to try it now

Comment: *I just thought of this in my head and im going to try it now* Then it's not an answer. It will be an answer after you implement it and find it works (hint: it won't).

Comment: and why wont it? The logic seems flawless. Also the answer section isnt for difinitive answers that will always work. People post suggestions and what they think will work. If it does, op gives it a tick and says it works fine